# Remove handler when usercontrol is disposing

Tags: c#, event-handling, dispose

Which one is the right one?

This one:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        this.ctlRBContent1_GetBuildName -= _ctlBottom.GetBuildName;
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

**OR**

This one:

```
~ ctlRemoteBuildContent1()
{
    this.ctlRBContent1_GetBuildName -= _ctlBottom.GetBuildName;
}
```

I tried to toggle this 2 functions. When I did UserControl disposing, it didn't jump into the toggle line :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you clean up in a [destructor](http://www.dotnetperls.com/destructor), there's no guarantee as to when the destructor will be run.  Objects with a destructor also require more work for the garbage collector to handle.  It's preferable therefore to implement IDisposable, which is your first example.

Note that your code snippet does not fully implement the recommended IDisposable pattern.  Please see this article for a good and complete explanation:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2010/02/c-garbage-collecting-destructors-versus-dispose/

In your code snippet, if for some reason `components` is null, you would not remove the event handler.  The null check for `components` should only be done to protect the `components.Dispose()` call.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        this.ctlRBContent1_GetBuildName -= _ctlBottom.GetBuildName;
        if (components != null)
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: So, I have to write on top of the "base.Dispose(disposing);" instead inside the nest of "if (disposing && (components != null))"?

Comment: Thank you very much. I toggled the line and it works perfect for me. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The second bit of code is called by the finalizer, which means you won't be able to tell when this is called (depends on when the garbage collector runs). Ideally you want to free your resources as soon as possible, typically in a Dispose(). So use the dispose pattern here.

Why do you want to unsubscribe that event here? What does it contain?

Comment: Formally it's called a destructor rather than finalizer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Comment: This event from this user control is calling another user control's function (listener). If after this user control is disposed, there is no way I could remove this event at the listener class.

Comment: A "destructor" is a C# construct which directs the compiler to generate a method called Finalize.  Since the term "destructor" is specific to C#, refers to something very different from the destructors in other languages like C++, and generates a method with the name "Finalize" which in all other .net languages is called a finalizer, I see no advantage to using the term "destructor", and think discussions would be clearer if that term were deprecated in favor of "finalizer", especially since the so-called "destructor" doesn't destroy things like the C++ destructor does.

Comment: @supercat: Microsoft decided to call this language construct a destructor.  Whether or not that is a good choice, it's not "so called", it _is_ called. `Although there has sometimes been a question as to whether destructors should be called "destructors" or "finalizers", the C# Language Specification, Version 3.0, released at the end of 2007, calls this method a destructor.` -Apress Illustrated C# 2008.  Since the example is C#, not VB.Net, not MISL, it is a destructor.

Comment: @Eric J.: The fact that code is written in C# does not mean that there isn't a finalizer.  If one wants to be very technical, a destructor in a C# class will generate a Finalize() method (finalizer) that combines the destructor for that class with a call to a base-class Finalize() method.  If the base class was written in C# and included a destructor, the base class Finalize() will run the code in that destructor and call its base class's Finalize() method.  I suppose I was a little hyperbolic in saying there was no advantage to the term "destructor", since calling Base.Finalize() is...

Comment: ...implicit with a destructor and explicit (if it's done at all) in a finalizer, so there is a semantic difference.  Nonetheless, it's by no means wrong, even in C#, to say something is called by the finalizer, since the finalization queue is used to invoke a finalizer which is defined by a C# destructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one is the right one?

A slightly obnoxious answer is "both" ;-) ...

Ideally you want the tidying up to happen in the Dispose method so it can be performed as soon as possible, but in some situations it's important to also have the tidy up code called from the destructor as a back-up in case an object gets used without being disposed (...I guess it depends on how likely you think this could be!?)

The dispose pattern (mentioned in the other answers) provides a way of implementing this without code duplication between the dispose and destructor, and with the GC.SupressFinalize makes sure the object's garbage collection doesn't get held up unnecessarily if the tidy up has been done.