# Does userControl1.Dispose() take care of all its disposable objects?

Tags: c#, dispose, user-controls, disposable

i have made a userControl library .. and it contains NetworkStream, StreamReader, FileStream

 So do i have to Dispose them all when the form that has this userControl closes ??

I mean There's no such `Form1_FormClosing(object sender,FormClosingEventArgs e)` in a userControl so when should i dispose those streams?
Does userControl1.Dispose() take care of that?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm assuming this is a win-forms question, if so could you update the tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserControl.Dispose()` disposes the components in it's `Controls` collection, but nothing more.

You can handle the `UserControl.Disposed` event, or you can [properly implement the Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx).

For C# user controls, `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` is auto-created in `UserControl1.Designer.cs`. You can amend it to:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (components != null)
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

        // Dispose your streams here
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`userControl1.Dispose()` does not magically take care of it unless you override it and put in code to dispose your objects, which is what you should do.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927933/remove-handler-when-usercontrol-is-disposing) to see how to implement it, replace the event de-regestering with your calls to dispose your streams.